# Try...catch not working when surrounding stored procedure execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my web api data access layer, the Asp.net TRY CATCH is NOT catching the fail of the stored procedure. Note: this template of code is used threw out my web api data access layer and works fine. Just not in this case. Weird!! (I included a similar and working example at the bottom).

I expect the stored procedure to fail as there are no rows that meet the criteria. So in that case, I raise an error (RAISERROR) and it writes an entry to my error log table.

This happens when I execute it via SSMS or running my web app that calls the web api that executes the stored procedure.

The error log table with 2 entries. 1 from running the stored procedure via SSMS and the other from running my web app.

[image]

The problem is the web api data access layer code execution does NOT catch the error returned by the stored procedure. It does NOT go into the CATCH.

[image]

Here is the web api data access layer function called from my web api controller. It has the TRY CATCH that is NOT working properly:

```
public List<BlogPublishedCategory> 
GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublishedList(string userName, string ipAddress)
{
   string userFriendlyMessage = "Unable to get the blog categorys in the 
   blogs published list. We have been notified and are working to resolve 
   this. Please do not continue.";

    List<BlogPublishedCategory> blogPublishedCategoryList = new 
    List<BlogPublishedCategory>();

    SqlDataReader blogCategorysInBlogsDataReader = null;

    try
    {
        dbFunc.OpenDB();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished", dbFunc.objConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserName", userName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_IpAddress", ipAddress);

        blogCategorysInBlogsDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (blogCategorysInBlogsDataReader.Read())
        {
            // Add to the list of BlogPublishedCategory - creates a new row for the collection.
            blogPublishedCategoryList.Add(new BlogPublishedCategory
            {
                BlogCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(blogCategorysInBlogsDataReader["BlogCategoryId"]),
                BlogCategoryDescr = blogCategorysInBlogsDataReader["BlogCategoryDescr"].ToString(),
            });
        }

        // Return the blogPublishedCategoryList object.
        return blogPublishedCategoryList;
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlex)
    {
    if (sqlex.Message.Contains("Critical"))
        {
            currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            sendAlertEmailResult = SendAlertEmailToStaff(currentDateTime, userName, ipAddress);

            if (sendAlertEmailResult == "")
            {
                throw new Exception(userFriendlyMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("In DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublishedList(). Sending an alert email for the initial sql exception error: " + sqlex.Message + ". Now getting this error: " + sendAlertEmailResult);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Sql Exception Error in DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublishedList(). Using 'GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished' s/p. Error: " + sqlex.Message;

            currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult = ProcessErrorLogAndSendAlertEmail(currentDateTime, userName, errorMessage, additionalInfoForLog, ipAddress);

            if (processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult != "")
            {
                throw new Exception("Error in DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublishedList(). Using 'GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished' s/p. Logging the initial sql exception error: " + sqlex.Message + ". Now getting this error: " + processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(userFriendlyMessage);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = "Error in DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublishedList(). Using 'GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished' s/p. Error: " + ex.Message;

        currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult = ProcessErrorLogAndSendAlertEmail(currentDateTime, userName, errorMessage, additionalInfoForLog, ipAddress);

        if (processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult != "")
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublishedList(). Using 'GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished' s/p. Logging the initial error: " + ex.Message + ". Now getting this error: " + processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(userFriendlyMessage);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (blogCategorysInBlogsDataReader != null)
        {
            blogCategorysInBlogsDataReader.Close();
        }

        dbFunc.CloseDB();
    }
}
```

The GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished stored proc (It fails as the rowcount is 0) :

```
USE [DBGbngDev]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo]. 
[GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    BEGIN
       DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished
    END
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished] 

@a_UserName              varchar(250) = NULL,
@a_IpAddress             varchar(250) = NULL

AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @RowCount                  int,
        @ReturnCode                int,
        @CurrentDateTime           datetime,  
        @Message                   varchar(max) = '',
        @ApiMessageOut             varchar(max),
        @ApiAccessSwitchOut        bit

DECLARE @ErrorLine          AS INT;
DECLARE @ErrorMessage       AS VARCHAR(2048);
DECLARE @ErrorNumber        AS INT; 
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity      AS INT; 
DECLARE @ErrorState         AS INT; 
DECLARE @DatabaseName       AS VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @ServerName         AS VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @ErrorDescription   AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF               AS VARCHAR(2);

SELECT @CurrentDateTime = GETDATE()
    
BEGIN TRY

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF ( ( @a_UserName  = '' OR @a_UserName  IS NULL ) 
   OR ( @a_IpAddress = '' OR @a_IpAddress IS NULL ) )
      BEGIN
         SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished - invalid 
         parameters. They cannot be null or empty.' 

         IF ( @a_UserName = '' OR @a_UserName IS NULL )
             BEGIN
                SET @a_UserName = 'No "user name" parameter provided.'
             END

         IF ( @a_IpAddress = '' OR @a_IpAddress IS NULL )
             BEGIN
                SET @a_IpAddress = 'No "ip address" parameter provided.'
             END

        RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
      END
   ELSE
      BEGIN
           -- Do the API security check. If this user is valid, you can continue with further
           processing.
           SELECT @ReturnCode = -1
           EXECUTE @ReturnCode = dbo.GetApiAccess
                              @CurrentDateTime,
                              @a_UserName,
                              @a_IpAddress,
                              @a_ApiAccessSwitchFromGet = @ApiAccessSwitchOut OUTPUT,
                              @a_ApiMessageFromGet = @ApiMessageOut OUTPUT

           IF @ReturnCode = -1
                BEGIN 
                   RAISERROR ('Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished failed during execute of procedure GetApiAccess.', 16, 1 )
                END
    
           -- Web api access was granted. 
           IF @ApiAccessSwitchOut = 1
               BEGIN    
                   SELECT DISTINCT (a.BlogCategoryId) as BlogCategoryId
                                   ,a.BlogCategoryDescr as BlogCategoryDescr
                   FROM dbo.BlogCategory a
                   JOIN dbo.Blog b On ( a.BlogCategoryId = b.BlogCategoryId )
                   WHERE ( b.PublishSwitch = 1 AND b.CanBeSeenSwitch = 1 )
                   ORDER BY a.BlogCategoryId asc  

                   SELECT @ReturnCode = @@ERROR,
                          @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

                   IF @ReturnCode <> 0
                       BEGIN 
                           SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished failed during the select.'
                           RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                       END
         
                   IF @RowCount = 0
                       BEGIN
                           SELECT @Message =  'Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished failed during the select. There are no BlogCategory entries.' 
                           RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                       END  
               END
           ELSE
               BEGIN
                    -- Web api access was NOT granted. The user did not have permission to use the web api or there is an error in the GetApiAccess procedure.
                    RAISERROR (@ApiMessageOut, 16, 1 )
              END
      END
    
   -- Returns success.
   RETURN 0

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
          @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE()
          -- ERROR_MESSAGE() contains the RAISERROR message raised above.
        , @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        , @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER()
        , @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        , @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()
        , @DatabaseName = CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARCHAR)
        , @ServerName = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY ( 'ServerName' ) AS VARCHAR)
        , @CRLF  = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

        SET @ErrorDescription = 'From stored procedure: '  + ERROR_PROCEDURE() 
                                + '. Error Line: '  + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR)
                                + '. Error Message: ' + @ErrorMessage
                                + ' Error Number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR)
                                + '. Error Severity: ' + CAST(@ErrorSeverity AS VARCHAR)
                                + '. Error State: ' + CAST(@ErrorState AS VARCHAR)
                                + '. Database Name: '  + @DatabaseName
                                + '. Server Name: ' + @ServerName

    IF (XACT_STATE() <> 0)
        BEGIN
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
        END
 
    IF (@ErrorSeverity = 16) AND (@ErrorState = 2)
        BEGIN 
           RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
        END      
    ELSE
        BEGIN 
           -- Log the critical error.   
           BEGIN TRY
              EXEC dbo.InsertBlogErrorLog
                         @a_LogDateTime = @CurrentDateTime,    
                         @a_UserName = @a_UserName,     
                         @a_UserIpAddress = @a_IpAddress,        
                         @a_ObjectID = @@PROCID,
                         @a_MessageType = 'S/P Critical Error',
                         @a_LogMessage = @ErrorDescription           
           END TRY

           BEGIN CATCH
              -- Stack the messages.
              SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure InsertBlogErrorLog failed. A log entry cannot be made. Do not continue. Contact IT. Initial error message: ' + @ErrorMessage
              RAISERROR(@Message, 16, 1) 
           END CATCH

           SELECT @message = 'Critical Error - do not continue. Contact IT and provide this log date: ' + Convert(VARCHAR, @CurrentDateTime,21)
           RAISERROR(@Message, 16, 1)                 
        END

     -- Returns failure.
     RETURN 1      

END CATCH
END
```

---

Here is a similar example whereby I force an error in a stored procedure to show that a similar (almost identical) web api data access layer function DOES catch the stored procedure error.

The error log table with the entry. From running my web api.

[image]

The web api data access layer code execution that DOES catch the error returned by the stored procedure. It DOES go into the CATCH and does the processing I expect.

[image]

Here is the web api data access layer function called from my web api controller. It has the TRY CATCH that IS working properly:

```
public List<BlogCategory> GetBlogCategoryList(string userName, string ipAddress)
    {
        string userFriendlyMessage = "Unable to get blog categories. We have been notified and are working to resolve this. Please do not continue.";

        List<BlogCategory> blogCategoryList = new List<BlogCategory>();

        SqlDataReader blogCategoryDataReader = null;

        try
        {
            dbFunc.OpenDB();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetBlogCategory", dbFunc.objConn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserName", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_IpAddress", ipAddress);

            blogCategoryDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

              while (blogCategoryDataReader.Read())
            {
                blogCategoryList.Add(new BlogCategory
                {
                    BlogCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(blogCategoryDataReader["BlogCategoryId"]),
                    BlogCategoryDescr = blogCategoryDataReader["BlogCategoryDescr"].ToString(),
                });
            }

            return blogCategoryList;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            if (sqlex.Message.Contains("Critical"))
            {
                // A "critical" error coming from the stored procedure.

                // So, send an alert email to a staff member (an Admin), but do NOT process the error log as it has been done already 
                // in the stored procedure.

                currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                sendAlertEmailResult = SendAlertEmailToStaff(currentDateTime, userName, ipAddress);

                if (sendAlertEmailResult == "")
                {
                    throw new Exception(userFriendlyMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("In DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategoryList(). Sending an alert email for the initial sql exception error: " + sqlex.Message + ". Now getting this error: " + sendAlertEmailResult);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Not coming from the stored procedure. Like if the stored procedure above was not named properly, does not exist, parameter missing, etc.
                errorMessage = "Sql Exception Error in DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategoryList(). Using 'GetBlogCategory' s/p. Error: " + sqlex.Message;

                // Log the error and send an alert email.
                currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult = ProcessErrorLogAndSendAlertEmail(currentDateTime, userName, errorMessage, additionalInfoForLog, ipAddress);

                if (processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult != "")
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error in DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategoryList(). Using 'GetBlogCategory' s/p. Logging the initial sql exception error: " + sqlex.Message + ". Now getting this error: " + processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(userFriendlyMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = "Error in DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategoryList(). Using 'GetBlogCategory' s/p. Error: " + ex.Message;

            currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult = ProcessErrorLogAndSendAlertEmail(currentDateTime, userName, errorMessage, additionalInfoForLog, ipAddress);

            if (processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult != "")
            {
                throw new Exception("Error in DataAccessLayer/GetBlogCategoryList(). Using 'GetBlogCategory' s/p. Logging the initial error: " + ex.Message + ". Now getting this error: " + processErrorLogAndSendAlertEmailResult);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(userFriendlyMessage);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (blogCategoryDataReader != null)
            {
                blogCategoryDataReader.Close();
            }

            dbFunc.CloseDB();
        }
    }
```

Here's the GetBlogCategory stored procedure (It fails as I force a rowcount = 0 ):

```
USE [DBGbngDev]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo]. 
[GetBlogCategory]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
   DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].GetBlogCategory
END
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetBlogCategory]

@a_UserName         varchar(250) = NULL,
@a_IpAddress        varchar(250) = NULL 

AS 
BEGIN

  DECLARE @RowCount                  int,
          @ReturnCode                int,
          @CurrentDateTime           datetime,  
          @Message                   varchar(max) = '',
          @ApiMessageOut             varchar(max),
          @ApiAccessSwitchOut        bit

SELECT @CurrentDateTime = GETDATE()

DECLARE @ErrorLine      AS INT;
DECLARE @ErrorMessage       AS VARCHAR(2048);
DECLARE @ErrorNumber        AS INT; 
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity      AS INT; 
DECLARE @ErrorState     AS INT; 
DECLARE @DatabaseName       AS VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @ServerName     AS VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @ErrorDescription   AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF           AS VARCHAR(2);
    
BEGIN TRY

   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF ( ( @a_UserName  = '' OR @a_UserName  IS NULL ) OR ( @a_IpAddress = '' OR @a_IpAddress IS NULL ) )
      BEGIN
         SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategory - invalid parameters. They cannot be null or empty.' 

         IF ( @a_UserName = '' OR @a_UserName IS NULL )
             BEGIN
                SET @a_UserName = 'No "user name" parameter provided.'
             END

         IF ( @a_IpAddress = '' OR @a_IpAddress IS NULL )
             BEGIN
                SET @a_IpAddress = 'No "ip address" parameter provided.'
             END

        RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
      END
   ELSE
      BEGIN
           -- Do the API security check. If this user is valid, you can continue with further processing.
           SELECT @ReturnCode = -1
           EXECUTE @ReturnCode = dbo.GetApiAccess
                              @CurrentDateTime,
                              @a_UserName,
                              @a_IpAddress,
                              @a_ApiAccessSwitchFromGet = @ApiAccessSwitchOut OUTPUT,
                              @a_ApiMessageFromGet = @ApiMessageOut OUTPUT

           IF @ReturnCode = -1
                BEGIN 
                   RAISERROR ('Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategory failed during execute of procedure GetApiAccess.', 16, 1 )
                END
    
           -- Web api access was granted. 
           IF @ApiAccessSwitchOut = 1
               BEGIN
                   --SELECT BlogCategoryId as BlogCategoryId
                            --    ,BlogCategoryDescr as BlogCategoryDescr
                   --FROM dbo.BlogCategory
                   --ORDER BY BlogCategoryDescr asc  

                   --SELECT @ReturnCode = @@ERROR,
                --                @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

                   --IF @ReturnCode <> 0
                      -- BEGIN 
                         --  SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategory failed during the select.'
                         --  RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                      -- END
             
                   SET @RowCount = 0

                   IF @RowCount = 0
                       BEGIN
                           SELECT @Message =  'Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategory failed during the select. There are no entries.' 
                           RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                       END  
               END
           ELSE
               BEGIN
                    -- Web api access was NOT granted. The user did not have permission to use the web api or there is an error in the GetApiAccess procedure.
                    -- Pass the message returned from the GetApiAccess procedure.
                    RAISERROR (@ApiMessageOut, 16, 1 )
              END
      END
    
   -- Returns success.
   RETURN 0

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT 
            @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE()
        -- ERROR_MESSAGE() contains the RAISERROR message raised above.
        , @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        , @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER()
        , @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        , @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()
        , @DatabaseName = CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARCHAR)
        , @ServerName = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY ( 'ServerName' ) AS VARCHAR)
        , @CRLF  = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)


        SET @ErrorDescription = 'From stored procedure: '  + ERROR_PROCEDURE() 
                                + '. Error Line: '  + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR)
                                            + '. Error Message: ' + @ErrorMessage
                        + ' Error Number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR)
                    + '. Error Severity: ' + CAST(@ErrorSeverity AS VARCHAR)
                        + '. Error State: ' + CAST(@ErrorState AS VARCHAR)
                        + '. Database Name: '  + @DatabaseName
                    + '. Server Name: ' + @ServerName

    IF (XACT_STATE() <> 0)
        BEGIN
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
        END
 
    IF (@ErrorSeverity = 16) AND (@ErrorState = 2)
        BEGIN 
           RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
        END      
     ELSE 
        BEGIN 
           -- Log the critical error.   
           BEGIN TRY
              EXEC dbo.InsertBlogErrorLog
                @a_LogDateTime = @CurrentDateTime,    
                @a_UserName = @a_UserName,     
                @a_UserIpAddress = @a_IpAddress,                     
                @a_ObjectID = @@PROCID,
                @a_MessageType = 'S/P Critical Error',
                @a_LogMessage = @ErrorDescription            
           END TRY

           BEGIN CATCH
              -- Stack the messages.
              SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure InsertBlogErrorLog failed. A log entry cannot be made. Do not continue. Contact IT. Initial error message: ' + @ErrorMessage
              RAISERROR(@Message, 16, 1) 
           END CATCH

           SELECT @message = 'Critical Error - do not continue. Contact IT and provide this log date: ' + Convert(VARCHAR, @CurrentDateTime,21)
           RAISERROR(@Message, 16, 1)                 
        END

     -- Returns failure.
     RETURN 1      

END CATCH
END
```

---

Dan...I put my original C# loop code back, I changed the failing s/p GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished where I completely removed the SELECT DISTINCT clause and just forced the RAISERROR by setting the @Rowcount = 0. The TRY CATCH in the web api function picks it up and processes properly.

[image]

I then in SSMS, took that SELECT DISTINCT an ran it.
In the Results tab, I see I get 2 results, the column headings and the error message column.

Could the 2 results be the issue?

[image]

In the Messages tab, I get: Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Critical Error - procedure GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished failed during the select. There are no BlogCategory entries.

[image]

I then in SSMS, force an error without a SELECT.
In the Results tab, I see I get just 1 column.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know, but could it be because RAISEERROR doesn't end the batch? It looks like THROW, which does, is the preferred call in SQL Server 2012 and later: [Differences Between RAISERROR and THROW in Sql Server](https://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/).

Comment: If you put `throw new Exception(userFriendlyMessage);` on the line after setting the value of `userFriendlyMessage`, does it do that? Just to make sure the exception isn't disappearing somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Make certain to consume all result sets in the data access layer to ensure exceptions are raised. An example pattern using `NextResult()`:

```
do {
    while (blogCategoryDataReader.Read())
    {
        blogCategoryList.Add(new BlogCategory
        {
            BlogCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(blogCategoryDataReader["BlogCategoryId"]),
            BlogCategoryDescr = blogCategoryDataReader["BlogCategoryDescr"].ToString(),
                });
            }
} while blogCategoryDataReader.NextResult();
```

The cause is that the exception message generated `RAISERROR` is behind the result set generated by the SELECT query in the underlying tabular data stream. This is effectively becomes multiple result sets that must be consumed by the client API so it is important to consume all results to [ensure exceptions are raised and can be detected](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/) by the client application.

Note that SSMS uses the [FireInfoMessagesOnUserErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.fireinfomessageeventonusererrors?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) connection property instead of try/catch to display user errors along with additional contextual information.

Comment: Dan..that worked. But odd as I have this similar code structure threw out my web api data access layer and they all work fine except this one. In my 2 examples, the one that does work, it's stored procedure just does a simple select whereby the failing example does a Select distinct and join. I don't understand what would make it behave this way.

Comment: I don't think the complexity of the select statement matters. The subsequent error won't get raised until the results are read. Try testing with a minimal proc like `CREATE PROC dbo.ErrorHandlingTest AS BEGIN TRY SELECT 1/0 AS oops; END TRY BEGIN CATCH THROW; END CATCH;`

Comment: Dan, I will try that minimal proc but the 2 examples above shows 1 works fine (whereby I force an error - a minimal test) and the other (selecting from the table where no rows exist). So, I basically have tried 2 test cases.

Comment: Dan, I put my original C# loop code back, I changed the failing s/p GetBlogCategorysInBlogsPublished where I completely removed the SELECT DISTINCT clause and just forced the RAISERROR by setting the @Rowcount =  0. The TRY CATCH picks it up and processes properly. So it must be that Select SELECT DISTINCT. I then created to tests in SSMS. They are  included above for review.

Comment: Dan...so now I get what your are saying in your solution code. In my test case, I can see that I was getting back 2 results and my C# loop code was only seeing the 1st results and not seeing the 2nd one which was the raiseerror.